# How to designer serialize the html color code property in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a color property like below and i have initialized the default value from html code with color translator like below,

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "#000000")]
public Color MyBorderColor { get; set;}

[DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "#0078d7")]
public Color MyBackColor { get; set;}
```

and i have initialized the default value with color translator like below.

```
MyBorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
MyBackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#0078d7");
```

For the **MyBorderColor** property, the designer serialization is not working properly.

I have given the serialize the property of MyBackColor too in same like the MyBorderColor property.

Could anyone please update me why designer code for MyBorderColor is generating?

Regards,
Amal

Comment: *For the MyBorderColor property, the designer serialization is not working properly.* - Add more description. It's not a suitable problem description.

Comment: issue is that the MyBorderColor property is serialized in forms designer event it is initialized with default value only.